# retrieving apr_pool_tag tag values

Tags: c, apache, apache-modules

I see that the [apr_pool_*](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.5/group__apr__pools.html#gaeaa872f7999740a60803e95429890518) interface exposes

`void  apr_pool_tag (apr_pool_t *pool, const char *tag)`

which lets me tag a pool.

That's all well and good, but how do I extract the tag from a pool at a later time? I can't find the "getter" for the above setter. How are these tags used?

Comment: Neither seems `tag` used anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trunk (aka 2.0) has an `apr_pool_get_tag()`, but in released branches pool tagging is meant as a debugging aid. In other words, post-mortem analysis with a debugger.